# Bash - How to get line numbers of file content using patterns that exist in another file?

Tags: bash, grep

I have a base file and pattern file like these:

base file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
include 'first.php';
$z=0;
function sayHello() {
   return "hellobye";
}
echo "<br /></br />";
?>
```

pattern file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php 
include 'first.php';
$z = 0;
echo "<br /></br />";
?>
```

So I want to extract lines with their numbers from base file that exist in pattern file using bash. also some of these patterns are unused and I want remove them. for example `<?php` and `?>`

The output should be like this:

```
1:#!/usr/bin/env php
3:include 'first.php';
4:$z = 0;
8:echo "<br /></br />";
```

another example is:

base file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env
<?php 
include 'second.php';
function saybye()
{
    return "bye";
}
echo "<br />";
function sayHello()
{
    return "hellobye";
}
?>
```

pattern file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env
<?php 
include 'second.php';
function saybye()
{
    return "bye";
}
echo "<br />";
?>
```

The output should be like this:

```
1:#!/usr/bin/env
3:include 'second.php';
4:function saybye()
5:{
6:    return "bye";
7:}
8:echo "<br />";
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you use `awk`? also can you update us with what you tried?

Comment: Also can you share the exact expected output for your input in question

Comment: How can you distinguish between "unused" and normal patterns?

Comment: @inian: The output should be like this: 
`1: #!/usr/bin/env php` `3: include 'first.php';` `4: $z = 0;` `8: echo "<br /></br />";`

Comment: @choroba: In my example just two `<?php` and `?>` are unused. these are constant and don't change.

Comment: Never use the word "pattern" as it's highly ambiguous, always use "regexp" or "string" (or "globbing pattern" for file name matching), whichever it is you mean. Do you want to search for the contents of "pattern file" as strings or regexps? Should they match only against the whole line or also parts of a line? Should they match irrespective of white space? What about partial matches? etc., etc....

Comment: @EdMorton: thanks for your guide. In my example I think regexp is correct. also match whole line is desired. generally I have two php files that one of them is base and another includes some parts of base file. so I should be able to extract lines (with their numbers) that exactly match between two files.

Comment: wrt `I think regexp is correct` - so when your `patterns` file contains the line `include 'first.php';` that is intended to match against `include 'first7php';` or `include 'firstAphp';` or any other character where the `.` regexp metacharacter is, right? And `$z = 0;` in `patterns` should not match against `$z = 0;` in `base` since the `$` regexp metacharacter would not match against the end of the line, right? I just want you to reallythink about what you're trying to do or you'll end up with a half-assed solution that "works" for some input and then fails cryptically later for other input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do a full-line string match between the 2 files:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN{ bad["<?php"]; bad["?>"]; OFS=";" }
    NR==FNR{ if ( !($0 in bad) ) good[$0]; next }
    $0 in good{ print FNR, $0 }
' pattern base
1;#!/usr/bin/env php
3;include 'first.php';
8;echo "<br /></br />";
```

Note that the `$z` line doesn't match since it has no space around the `=` in the `base` file but space around `=` in the `pattern` file:

```
$ grep '$z' pattern base
pattern:$z = 0;
base:$z=0;
```

If you want all white space to be completely ignored you could do:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN{ bad["<?php"]; bad["?>"]; OFS=";" }
    { nospace=$0; gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"",nospace) }
    NR==FNR{ if ( !(nospace in bad) ) good[nospace]; next }
    nospace in good{ print FNR, $0 }
' pattern base
1;#!/usr/bin/env php
3;include 'first.php';
4;$z=0;
8;echo "<br /></br />";
```

but then you have to be careful that concatenations can produce false matches. If you want all space to be treated equally you could do:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN{ bad["<?php"]; bad["?>"]; OFS=";" }
    { anyspace=$0; gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,RS,anyspace) }
    NR==FNR{ if ( !(anyspace in bad) ) good[anyspace]; next }
    anyspace in good{ print FNR, $0 }
' pattern base
1;#!/usr/bin/env php
3;include 'first.php';
8;echo "<br /></br />";
```

but note that sill doesn't find the `$z` line as there is no space around the `=` in one of the files. If you wanted to treat every punctuation character as if it was surrounded by a space while still doing a string comparison you could do:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN{ bad[RS"<"RS"?"RS"php"]; bad[RS"?"RS">"RS]; OFS=";" }
    { anyspace=$0; gsub(/[[:punct:]]/," & ",anyspace); gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,RS,anyspace) }
    NR==FNR{ if ( !(anyspace in bad) ) good[anyspace]; next }
    anyspace in good{ print FNR, $0 }
' pattern base
1;#!/usr/bin/env php
3;include 'first.php';
4;$z=0;
8;echo "<br /></br />";
```

Once you clarify your requirements we can help you write a script to do whatever it is you really want to do whether it's a string or regexp comparison, whether a partial or full match is needed, and whether white space should be treated literally or ignored.

Comment: Your solution is perfect. I have another example. if we have 
base:
`#!/usr/bin/env
<?php 
include 'second.php';
function saybye()
{
    return "bye";
}
echo "<br />";
function sayHello()
{
    return "hellobye";
}
?>`
pattern:
`#!/usr/bin/env
<?php 
include 'second.php';
function saybye()
{
    return "bye";
}
echo "<br />";
?>`
result:
`1;#!/usr/bin/env
2;<?php 
3;include 'second.php';
4;function saybye()
5;{
6;    return "bye";
7;}
8;echo "<br />";
10;{
12;}
13;?>
` what is your idea about this and how we can ignore lines 10 and 12?

Comment: You can't put formatted text in a comment, you need to put all formatted input, output, and code in your question, but in any case I won't be able to keep updating my answer one example at a time, sorry. Maybe it's time for you to post a followup question with new input/output and requirements if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Try a simple `grep -nf`.

```
$grep -nf pattern base
1:#!/usr/bin/env php
3:include 'first.php';
4:$z = 0;
8:echo "<br /></br />";
9:?>
```

If you want to remove the line starting with "?>"

```
$grep -nf pattern base | grep -v "?>"
1:#!/usr/bin/env php
3:include 'first.php';
4:$z = 0;
8:echo "<br /></br />";
```

Where the inputs are-

```
$cat pattern

#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php 
include 'first.php';
$z = 0;
echo "<br /></br />";
?>
```

and

```
$cat base
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
include 'first.php';
$z = 0;
function sayHello() {
   return "hellobye";
}
echo "<br /></br />";
?>
```

Comment: I try  `grep -nf pattern base | grep -v "?>" | grep -v "<?php"` and output is:
`1:#!/usr/bin/env php
3:include 'first.php';
4:$z=0;
5:function sayHello() {
6:   return "hellobye";
7:}
8:echo "<br /></br />";`

lines 5 through 7 shouldn't appear in output.

Comment: Umm I don't know why that should be happening. Both mine and the solution by @0xAX should give the correct output. Please check that your input files are fine.

Comment: I checked them. they are exactly files in my question!

Comment: @F.Ndr if you have a blank line or a line that's just a `.` or various other things in your `pattern` file then that will cause the behavior you are seeing since this solution is doing a regexp match on any part of the line in base. You have to be clear in your requirements - regexp or string match and partial or full matches only.

Answer (score 0):

There is posibility to do it with grep and two sed calls:

```
$ grep -nFwf file1 test2 | sed s/\?// | sed /[0-9].*\:\>/d 
1:#!/usr/bin/env php
3:include 'first.php';
4:$z=0;
8:echo "<br /></br />";
```

Where file1:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php 
include 'first.php';
$z=0;
echo "<br /></br />";
?>
```

file2:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
include 'first.php';
$z=0;
function sayHello() {
   return "hellobye";
}
echo "<br /></br />";
?>
```

The `grep` call will produce output of matched lines and last two sed calls will remove `?>` and `<?php` patterns.

Comment: I try `grep -nFwf file1 test2 | sed s/\<// | sed /[0-9].*\:\?/d` but output is :
`1:#!/usr/bin/env php
3:include 'first.php';
4:$z=0;
5:function sayHello() {
6:   return "hellobye";
7:}
8:echo "<br /></br />";
`
line 5 through 7 should be removed.

Comment: what if `file1 test2` -> `test2 file1`?

Comment: The output is incorrect in this way: `2:#!/usr/bin/env php
4:include 'first.php';
6:echo "br /></br />";
`

Comment: A blank line in your `pattern` file would cause this behavior. See my other comments.